# Problem installing ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop

Tags: system-installation

I'm using lenovo Ideapad S540

there is 2 kind of problem

-using 'try ubuntu without install" option

when I getting into drive allocation page, there is nothing but blank, and soon system freezes.

-using 'install ubuntu' option

I get error message like this

```
mmc0: Unknown controller version(3). You May experience problem
usb usbx-portx: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad
usb usbx-portx: Unable to enumerate USB device
(initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system
```

I checked my bootable usb stick and it worked fine on other computer.

Comment: Did you 'check install media' first?  ie. verify you had a perfect download of the ISO & write to your install media (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck)   It would be my first step.  (The image will be different to my link, but the check CD for defects option will be detectable).  On some boxes you need to press a key (when you see *keyboard-in-box* & *person-in-circle* to make the menu appear, others machines it appears regardless.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved.
It was SATA control mode issue.
I changed it from RST to ACHI and everything is OK.